# Get max on comma separated values in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to get max on comma separated values in Original_Ids column and get max value in one column and remaining ids in different column.

```
|Original_Ids   | Max_Id| Remaining_Ids |
|123,534,243,345| 534   | 123,234,345 |
```

**Upadte** - 
If I already have Max_id and just need below equation?

```
  Remaining_Ids = Original_Ids - Max_id
```

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first case

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the excellent possibilities of array manipulation in Postgres, this could be done relatively easy by converting the string to an array and from there to a set.

Then regular queries on that set are possible. With `max()` the maximum can be selected and with `EXCEPT ALL` the maximum can be removed from the set.

A set can then be converted to an array and with `array_to_string()` and the array can be converted to a delimited string again.

```
SELECT ids original_ids,
       (SELECT max(un.id::integer)
               FROM unnest(string_to_array(ids,
                                           ',')) un(id)) max_id,
       array_to_string(ARRAY((SELECT un.id::integer
                                     FROM unnest(string_to_array(ids,
                                                                 ',')) un(id)
                              EXCEPT ALL
                              SELECT max(un.id::integer)
                                     FROM unnest(string_to_array(ids,
                                                                 ',')) un(id))),
                       ',') remaining_ids
       FROM elbat;
```

Another option would have been `regexp_split_to_table()` which directly produces a set (or `regexp_split_to_array()` but than we'd had the possible regular expression overhead and still had to convert the array to a set).

**But nevertheless you just should (almost) never use delimited lists (nor arrays).** Use a table, that's (almost) always the best option.

Comment: Thanks , it gives expected result but adds complexity since I already have few logic . I have edited the question , is there easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a05e8/4)

You can use a window function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to get the max element per unnested array. After that you can reaggregate the elements and remove the calculated max value from the array.

Result:

```
a                     max_elem     remaining
123,534,243,345       534          123,243,345
3,23,1                23           3,17
42                    42           
56,123,234,345,345    345          56,123,234
```

This query needs only one split/unnest as well as only one max calculation.

```
SELECT 
    a,
    max_elem,
    array_remove(array_agg(elements), max_elem) as remaining      -- C
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        MAX(elements) OVER (PARTITION BY a) as max_elem           -- B
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            a, 
            unnest((string_to_array(a, ','))::int[]) as elements  -- A
        FROM arrays
    )s
)s
GROUP BY a, max_elem
```

A: `string_to_array` converts the string list into an array. Because the arrays are treated as string arrays you need the cast them into integer arrays by adding `::int[]`. The `unnest()` expands all array elements into own rows.

B: window function `MAX` gives the maximum value of the single arrays as `max_elem`

C: `array_agg` reaggregates the elements through the `GROUP BY id`. After that `array_remove` removes the `max_elem` value from the array.

If you do not like to store them as pure arrays but as string list again you could add `array_to_string`. But I wouldn't recommend this because your data are integer arrays and not strings. For every further calculation you would need this string cast. A even better way (as already stated by @stickybit) is not to store the elements as arrays but as unnested data. As you can see in nearly every operation should would do the `unnest` before.

**Note:**

It would be better to use an ID to adress the columns/arrays instead of the origin string as in [SQL Fiddle with IDs](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/933be8/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you install the extension [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) this is quite easy.

First you need to create the extension (you have to be superuser to do that):

```
create extension intarray;
```

Then you can do the following:

```
select original_ids, 
       original_ids[1] as max_id,
       sort(original_ids - original_ids[1]) as remaining_ids
from (       
  select sort_desc(string_to_array(original_ids,',')::int[]) as original_ids
  from bad_design
) t
```

---

But you shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with

Comment: Thanks , it looks cleaner solution but the document says that it will throw error for any NULL value . The input data is from upstream and we have no control over it .